# Getting sass css modules to show up when using enzyme with gatsby

Tags: sass, jestjs, enzyme, gatsby, css-modules

So I'm having issues when I use enzyme to test a component thats using css modules. Or should I say **filename.module.scss**

Whats happening when I do something like:

```
const wrapper = shallow(<MyComponent {...data}/>);
console.log('wrapper = ', wrapper.debug());
```

My debug works and shows my component structure with all my divs in there. The issue is none of my styles are getting added durning running tests. But when I run Gatsby develop the styles are getting added. **So just to be clear only in test mode do I not see the styles added to my component!!!**

**MyComponent.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import styles from ‘./MyComponent.module.scss';

class MyComponent extends Component {

  render() {
    const {
      name,
    } = this.props;

    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <div className={styles.header}>
        <div className={styles.name}>{name}</div>
        </div>
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}
```

My debug is showing all styles as **undefined** which is driving me crazy as I can't test based on style name if a div exists.

Here is my package setup for jest.

```
  "jest": {
    "moduleNameMapper": {
      "\\.(css|scss)$": "<rootDir>/.jest/styleMock.js"
    },
    "setupFiles": [
      "<rootDir>/.jest/setupFiles.js"
    ]
  }
```

Answer (score 3):

For anyone else running into this issue.

```
npm install identity-obj-proxy
```

then add this to your package.json

```
  "jest": {
    "moduleNameMapper": {
      ".+\\.(css|styl|sass|scss)$": "identity-obj-proxy"
    },
    "setupFiles": [
      "<rootDir>/.jest/setupFiles.js"
    ]
  }
```

Hope this helps someone.